# Display some data from sql database

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have a database on phpmyadmin (sql) and I want to display some data on php.

```
<?php
session_start();
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
require_once 'src/db.php';
require_once 'src/config.php';

/* Taking other user data from database. */
$a = mysql_query("select * from instagram_users"); 
while($b = mysql_fetch_array($a))
?>
```

I only want to display 10 data from existing data 1000

example :

```
id 210 = john 
id 211 = slamet 
id 212 = kikuk 
...
id 220 = yuni
```

Comment: do `select top 10 * from.....`

Comment: if you are using `MySQL` use `select * from instagram_users LIMIT 10`

Comment: Please edit the question to exactly what you are looking for. You have two comments in two answers that vary. If just want 10 it is `limit 10`. `The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be nonnegative integer constants (except when using prepared statements).` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: Please be aware that the `mysql_` functions are now no longer just discouraged (as it was over the last years), but officially [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php). You should really use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php), as this code will stop working very soon. Also see [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [LIMIT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) clause. Just replace this line:

```
$a = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM instagram_users LIMIT 10");
```

Comment: I want to display 10 or 15 data based on 'id'

Comment: Linking to the primary source, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html, is best.

Comment: @chris85 you are totally right! Edited!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
session_start();
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
require_once 'src/db.php';
require_once 'src/config.php';

/* Taking other user data from database. */
$a = mysql_query("select * from instagram_users limit 10"); 
while($b = mysql_fetch_array($a))
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `LIMIT` with offset & count like below:

```
 $a = mysql_query("select * from instagram_users LIMIT 40,10");
```

Comment: I have 1000 the data, how can I display of the data from 40 to 50

Comment: That will return rows 41- 90, I believe. `With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of rows to return.`

Comment: edited the answer according to your question. please check it

Comment: Thats going to bring back records 41-50. 40 to 50 is actually 11 numbers. You also need to start the offset lower. Please look at the documentation, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html.